# Pulling substring results in Nullpointer

Tags: java, string, substring

I've been assigned a project where I have to create a login system in java, using filein to write the accounts to an array, and using that array to log in by confirming the input username is the same as a username in the array. My usernames and passwords are on the same line in the .txt file that's being read, so I'm trying to pull the substring from the beginning of the string to the first space, and it results in this when user input is in:

EDIT: When trying to isolate, I somehow fixed it. When adding the infile and array back in, it results in the error again.

EDIT: I've added an accountCounter so that it only loops through as many times as there are array values that aren't null. Unfortunately I'm still running into the error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at zamp.main(zamp.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

In all instances of trying to grab the substring (printing it, delegating it to a separate string) it results in that.

Here's my code!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.net.*;  //handles the network protocols

public class zamp {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      Scanner yiff = new Scanner(System.in); 
      BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("passwords.txt"));


      String searchuser;
      int f;
      int i;
      int accountnumber=0;
      String modernPass="i";
        String[] accounts = new String[5];
      String searchpass;
        String line = infile.readLine();

      for(i=1; i<11; i++){   
        if (line!=null) { 
       accounts[i]=line;
       System.out.println(""+accounts[i]);
       line=infile.readLine();
       accountnumber++;


 }
 }



System.out.println("Enter your username.");
     searchuser=yiff.nextLine();
     for (f=0; f<(accountnumber); f++) {
  modernPass=(""+(accounts[f].substring(0, ((accounts[f].indexOf(" "))))));

        if (searchuser.equals(modernPass)) {

        System.out.println("Enter your password.");

        searchpass=yiff.nextLine();
        }

        else {
        }
     }
   }}
```

`passwords.txt` has

```
user1 password1
user2 password2
```

I'm sure the solution is incredibly simple!

Thanks again for any help, sincerely, a student with a deadline in 3 hours.

Comment: It might be helpful to say *how* it's "breaking everything". We can't read your mind. In addition, please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). The code you have is next to useless to someone trying to help.

Comment: Where do you set `accounts[0]`?

Comment: Yep, you'll want to post any and all error messages. We're often not too good at guessing.

Comment: Voting to put on hold. Read the Help Center and update your question accordingly.

Comment: We are here spending our time to offer free help but to help as many as we can we prefer or maybe even require minimal code which reproduces your problem. Take your time and create [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question with it (do to so use [[edit]] option under your post). Oh and don't forget to use proper indentation to make reading your code easier (showing scope is important). Last thing: beside showing that code is not working it is worth to describe **how** it is not working (what results you expect and what you get instead?).

Comment: Alright, I'll edit it, thanks for the guidelines. :) First time poster and student.

Comment: @user3755473 As a note for next time, the very first thing that pops out with this question is that "Substring is breaking Java" almost sounds like you're blaming `substring()` for your problems. Wording a question to make it sound like it's the standard library's fault is almost a surefire way to get downvotes since more than 99.99% of the time, it wasn't.

Comment: Oh whoops! Sorry about that, I meant this line in which I'm pulling a substring from. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that asking a question here should be much like asking a teacher/prof/TA the same question. If you asked this question verbatim to someone, you'd almost certainly get blank stares and requests for more details, because just saying "My program doesn't work, and here it is" isn't very helpful -- and that's for people who actually know your assignment!. Put yourself in your answerer's shoes. Don't assume that we have prior knowledge of your problem. Share what you've researched, what you've tried, and the results. Things like that. Reading the help center is a good place to start.

Comment: I've updated it, hopefully it's easier to read!

Comment: 1+ up-vote for trying to improve your question. Anyone else going to follow suit?

Comment: Removed the -1 for the improvement, but no +1 yes, as there is a minor problem: the code you provided doesn't throw the given exception. I *think* I know what is wrong, though...

Comment: Huh, now I'm wondering if the issue might be with my code that writes the infile to the array, since it doesn't throw it in the new code. Should I add that?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. I think that could be at least part of the problem, along with any time you use `indexOf()` as ajb noted in the answer section. His answer was what I was thinking of

Comment: I've added the bit that's started causing the problem.

Comment: OK, now think about how big your array is compared to how many inputs you have. If you have fewer inputs than you do spaces in your array, you'll have `null` elements, right? And what happens when you try to dereference `null` elements with `accounts[f].indexOf()`?

Comment: You get -1 instead of a value! Right... how do I avoid this? Should I loop through all the elements adding +1 to a counter and then make the for loop  for (f=0; f<(elementCounter); f++) ?

Comment: No, not quite... If you have an array with 5 elements, and you have 2 inputs, the elements at indices 2-4 are `null`, right? And because you're iterating from `0` to `accounts.length - 1`, what would happen when you try `accounts[2].indexOf()`, for example? Remember, only `accounts[0]` and `accounts[1]` actually have something in them...

Comment: Looks like you figured out the start to a solution, though. You don't want to add `1` to a counter for *all* elements, but only for *some* elements... But which ones? (also, as a side note, are you allowed to use an `ArrayList`?)

Comment: Would cycling through it with if (accounts[f]!=null)  work? And no, we haven't been taught it. From a google search, it seems beyond what we're covering.

Comment: It isn't the *best* solution, but if you do it right, it *should* work (for the `NullPointerException` at least, I believe)

Comment: Your way of reading lines from file has buggy since you don't fill index `[0]` but you place lines starting in `[1]`. Also since you have only two lines and array of 5 elements some of them will be `null`s which means that in some place `accounts[f].substring(..)` will be same as calling `null.substring(..)` and since `null` doesn't have any fields you are seeing NullPointerExcelption. Instead of arrays you should use `List` which is dynamic structure and can grow each time you will add line to it.

Comment: Oh, if you haven't been taught `ArrayList`, I would be a bit wary of using it... But as Pshemo pointed out, it's a dynamic structure that can resize itself, which would eliminate the need for `null` checks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think we can use it since it's the final project for an array culminating. Is there a way of filling 0?

Comment: "Is there a way of filling 0?" yes, just start from `i=0` instead of `i=1` in your loops, same about `f=0` (actually you don't even need to declare two different variables, just iterate `i` each time in your for loop like `for(int i=...;..;i++)`). Also if you don't know how many lines there is in file then simply iterate over it without writing them to array and just count them. Then you can create array with appropriate size and use its length in for loop to iterate over it like `for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){System.out.println(array[i]);}`.

Comment: Question: Why are you starting your loops at 0? Pretty sure that's at least part of the reason you are getting exceptions

Comment: I've added all this in (counter, starting from 0), it all works! Thank you all so so much! Where can I credit these comments for the solution?

Comment: I'll go ahead post something in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Going off your most recent edit)

You're almost there. The only thing is that when you fill in the array from the file, you insert starting from index 1. This leaves index 0 `null`.

This causes a problem because when you go to process your data, you start from index 0 -- a guaranteed `NullPointerException`.

Either read in your data starting from index 0, or use null checks (i.e. `if (_____ != null)`) to avoid this problem.

---

In the future, looking into [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)  and other resizable [`List`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) will make your life significantly easier for tasks like this. Alternatively, if you're willing to read the file twice you can always read it once to determine how many items there are, create an array with that size, then read in the data for real.

In addition, your first `for` loop reading in the data is probably written better as a `while` loop:

```
while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
    // read in data
}
```

Finally, I'd also suggest learning to use a debugger. It's an incredibly valuable tool to inspect your program while it is running to learn how it is executing.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting out of your array bounds.

Try to rewrite

```
for (f=0; f<=(accounts.length); f++)
```

as

```
for (f=0; f<(accounts.length); f++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
modernPass=(""+(accounts[f].substring(0, ((accounts[f].indexOf(" "))))));
```

The stack trace says you're getting an `index out of range` in `substring`, and it says that one of parameters is -1.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) for `indexOf` says,

> if no such character occurs in this string, then -1 is returned.